# Weak Convergence to Normal Distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with mean $0$ and finite variance.  I want to show that the sequence $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2)^{1/2}}$$
converges weakly to $N(0,1)$.  My first thought is to use characteristic functions, but I'm not aware of a way to compute indicator functions of a quotient.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint. you can use the law of large numbers (and the [Slutsky theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) if required) to replace the denominator by $\mathrm{Var}(X_1 + ... + X_n)^{1/2}$ without changing the distributional limit.